# Facebook Photo Upload in C#?

Tags: silverlight, facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to upload an photo to Facebook from a Windows Phone Silverlight application using the Facebook Graph API but I am getting an error: (#324) Requires upload file.  Can anyone see anything wrong in my code?

```
    internal void PublishPhoto(System.IO.MemoryStream stream, string message, string accessToken)
    {
        var requestUriString = string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
            "https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/photos?access_token={1}&message={2}",
            "me",
            accessToken,
            message);

        var webRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(requestUriString);

        webRequest.Method = "POST";

        var boundary = "7db3d9202a1";
        webRequest.ContentType = string.Format("multipart/form-data; boundary={0}", boundary);

        webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(delegate (IAsyncResult result)
            {
                GetRequestStream(stream, boundary, result);

                BeginGetResponse(webRequest);

            }), webRequest);
    }

    private static void GetRequestStream(System.IO.MemoryStream imageStream, string boundary, IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var webRequest2 = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;

        using (var requestStream = webRequest2.EndGetRequestStream(result))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("--{0}\r", boundary);
                writer.WriteLine("Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"sketch.jpg\"\r");
                writer.WriteLine("Content-Type: image/jpg\r");

                byte[] buffer = imageStream.GetBuffer();
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                writer.WriteLine("\r");
                writer.WriteLine("--{0}--\r", boundary);
            }

            imageStream.Close();
        }
    }

    private static void BeginGetResponse(HttpWebRequest webRequest)
    {
        webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(delegate(IAsyncResult result2)
        {
            var webRequest2 = result2.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;

            try
            {
                using (var response = webRequest2.EndGetResponse(result2))
                {
                    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException we)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(we.Message);

                using (var responseStream = we.Response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        var errorJson = reader.ReadToEnd();

                        var response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookErrorResponse>(errorJson);

                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Could not upload image to Facebook: {0}", response.Error.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }), webRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a name of "source" as well as a filename in the Content-Disposition header, i.e.

```
writer.WriteLine("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"source\"; filename=\"sketch.jpg\"\r");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I just tried it but got the same result.

Comment: Your boundary is also wrong. All except the last should use a format of `"--{0}\r"` instead of just `"{0}\n"`; the last should be `"--{0}--\r"`.

Comment: the boundary string aleady has hyphens: var boundary = "---------------------------7db3d9202a1"; I can fix the last one and try again.

Comment: When you set `multipart/form-data; boundary=foo`, then all boundaries except the last must be `--foo` (and the last is `--foo--`). If you set `multipart/form-data; boundary=--foo`, all boundaries except the last must be `----foo` with two *more* hyphens at the beginning.

Comment: Anomie,That didn't work either. I updated the code in the question to what I'm using, and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was wrong the first time around, but now I have it.

The first problem, which we already took care of above, was that you were missing the "--" before each boundary and the "--" after the last boundary in the POST body.

The second problem is that you're not leaving a blank line after the MIME headers before writing the image content.

The third problem is that you're not flushing the `writer` before writing the image data to its underlying stream (unless silverlight on a phone is different from normal .NET in auto-flushing StreamWriters).

To sum up, this should work:

```
            writer.WriteLine("--{0}\r", boundary);
            writer.WriteLine("Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"sketch.jpg\"\r");
            writer.WriteLine("Content-Type: image/jpg\r");
            writer.WriteLine("\r");
            writer.Flush();

            byte[] buffer = imageStream.GetBuffer();
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            writer.WriteLine("\r");
            writer.WriteLine("--{0}--\r", boundary);
```

Comment: No idea then, it works for me when I put your code in a project and make the above change.

Comment: Anomie, does it actually upload and show the image on your Facebook profile?

Comment: I uploaded it to an album I use for testing uploads rather than to "me", but that worked fine.